# Need help on a linked list contains method

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a question on linked list. I have 2 classes. one called countryNode and 2nd called countryList. CountryNode takes 2 parameters, a variable object called country and a variable called next of type countryNode. CountryList takes 1 parameter called first of type countryNode that hold the link list of countryNode object. First i created A method “add()” that takes a Country object as parameter and adds that new object to the end of the list. which i did. Below is the code for countryList:

```
public void add(Country country) {
    CountryNode a = new CountryNode(country);
    CountryNode current = null;
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        a.set(first);
        first = a;
    }
    else{
        current = first;
        while(current.getNext()!=null)
        {
             current = current.getNext();
        }
        current.set(a);
    }

}
```

The question i have trouble understanding is this: A method "contains" that takes a Country object as parameter and checks if the name of the country can be found in the list. to check whether object foo of type Country equals objects bar of type Country, you must override the "equals method" in class Country. I have trouble understanding the question and implementing it.

Below is code i wrote for country, countryNode.

```
public class Country {

private String countryNames;
private SubscriptionYear[] subscriptions;
private int size;
private int location;

public Country(String country, int arraylength)
{
    this.countryNames = country;
    this.size = arraylength;
    subscriptions = new SubscriptionYear[size];
    location = 0;
}

public void addSubscriptionYear(int year, double subscription)
{
        subscriptions[location]= new SubscriptionYear(year, subscription);
        ++location;
}

public double getNumSubscriptionsForPeriod(int start, int end)
{
    double sum = 0;

    int head = start-subscriptions[0].getYear();
    int tail = head+(end-start);

    if(head>=0&&tail<subscriptions[subscriptions.length-1].getYear())
    {
    for(int k=head;k<=tail;k++)
    {
        sum += subscriptions[k].getSubscription();
    }
    }else{ sum = -1;}
    return sum;
    }

public String toString()
{
    System.out.print(countryNames+"\t");
    for(SubscriptionYear s: subscriptions)
    {
        //System.out.print(countryNames+"\t");
        System.out.print(s.getSubscription()+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
    return  "";
}
}
```

My code countryNode:

```
public class CountryNode {
private Country country;
private CountryNode next;

public CountryNode(Country country)
 {
   this.country = country;
   this.next = null;
 }
 public CountryNode(Country country, CountryNode n)
{
 this.country = country;
 this.next = n;
}

public void set(CountryNode x)
{
 this.next = x;
}
public CountryNode getNext()
{
 return this.next;
}
public Country getCountry()
{
 return country;
}

}
```

Comment: While I sympathise, it is NOT ON to ask us to write your code for you.  Especially homework code ... as this appears to be.  Go to bed.  Get some sleep.  Write the code for the `contains` method tomorrow, and if you still have problems ... show us your attempt at writing it.

Answer (score 0):

The equals() method provided by Java always checks for equality of references and will return the result as two if the two objects being compared point to the same reference. Considering your code, if you create two Country objects like below and compare them, the result will be false as they are not pointing to the same reference.

```
Country c1=new Country("abc", 10);
Country c2=new Country("abc", 10);
```

This is why we override the equals method to compare the contents of the object and not the references. Not sure if this answers your question completely coz I didnt get the whole question.